# what is the reason to get higher loss and val_loss?

Tags: python, neural-network

I have coded Neaural network.

Dataset is like:

```
aqi timestamp   junctionid  Dates   Time    Day

0   94  2014-08-01 00:05:00 1   2014-08-01  5   0
1   90  2014-08-01 00:10:00 1   2014-08-01  10  0
2   85  2014-08-01 00:15:00 1   2014-08-01  15  0
3   85  2014-08-01 00:20:00 1   2014-08-01  20  0
4   84  2014-08-01 00:25:00 1   2014-08-01  25  0
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
95  95  2014-08-01 08:00:00 1   2014-08-01  480 0
96  90  2014-08-01 08:05:00 1   2014-08-01  485 0
97  91  2014-08-01 08:10:00 1   2014-08-01  490 0
98  92  2014-08-01 08:15:00 1   2014-08-01  495 0
99  96  2014-08-01 08:20:00 1   2014-08-01  500 0
```

Code :

```
    Y = dataset[['aqi']]
    X = dataset[['Day','Time','junctionid']]
    X_scale =X

    # normalize the dataset
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 0.99))
    Y = scaler.fit_transform(Y['aqi'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

    from sklearn import preprocessing
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size=0.3)
    X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size=0.5)
    print(X_train.shape, X_val.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_val.shape, Y_test.shape)

    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense

    model = Sequential([
        Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(3,)),
        Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
    ])

    history = model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

    hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
              batch_size=70, epochs=5,
              validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
```

What would be the reason to get  loss: 0.0369 - val_loss: 0.0368?

Comment: FYI you want three backticks for code blocks not three apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

Loss will be the mean squared error between all data in your training dataset. The validation dataset is different and not used as part of training. Validation is when you test the network on data that is not included in the training set to ensure the network is able to generalize to all data and is not over fitting the training set.

It is possible that the network weights have optimized to a point where they are more accurate when predicting the validation data. This is by chance, and the difference will usually be very minimal which it is in your example.